# asp.net Attempting to create publish settings in vs 2012 gives strange error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web-config

I recently updated my asp.net 3.5 web project from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2012.  Every time I try to create publish settings it says the following:

> {There are errors in web.config.  Please correct these errors and try again.
>   The first error is: "Web.config appears to be in invalid state.  Please correct it and try again."}

I have been unable to determine what this means.  I have no errors in my web.config that it is telling me about.  I have search for this error and have come up with nothing.

Can someone please help me out?

I should also mention this entire project resides on a mapped drive.  I am still able to open the project and publish it in Visual Studio 2010 but can't even create the publish settings in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Positive your web.config is valid. Have you attempted to run it locally?

Comment: Yes.  I can run it locally just fine.  Just can't create publish settings.

Comment: Have you looked in your web.config transform files too? Like `web.release.config` and `web.debug.config`?

Comment: I don't have any on this project.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below steps would help you out.

1. Before performing publish make sure the project is changed to Release mode.
2. Do not perform publish as a website. Try and publish your website to a file system.
3. create a virtual directory and point that virtual directory to the published folder.

The above mentioned steps worked for me.